# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate concurrency

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to use the

```
findAndUpdate
```

method in mongo to generate a sequence.  This works just fine as long as mongodb/mongoose only allows one query to be executed at a time per table/collection.

Comment: If I understand, you want a sort of transaction?

Comment: I think mongoose guarantees that one one query per collection can execute at a time, so I think that I am ok.

Comment: Link? Because in mongodb, only a document keeps the lock.